# AEM+Filevault+Intellij integration

Tags: intellij-idea, aem

I am working on AEM 6.2 with crx mapped to local file system using filevault. I also have my code in svn for ui.apps which is in intellij.

Problem: If i change any component dialog, first i need to sync my crx with local file system and then copy changes from file system to svn folder.

I tried to integrate intellij using vlt commands but getting message

> File is under version control

Is there a way i can club all three together so from IDE i can update code repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [IntelliVault](https://github.com/shsteimer/IntelliVault) plugin to push content to or pull it from CRX.

In such a setup it doesn't matter where your CRX actually sits. You keep a set of files under version control and the IDE plugin allows you to push/pull to/from CRX whenever you want to. It uses the Vault command line tool under the hood.

It's probably not exactly what you're asking about but it works for me.

Another option is to use [*AEM Sync*](https://github.com/gavoja/aemsync) from the command line. It's a Node package that you can use to listen to file changes. Have it running in the background and changes you make in your IDE will be automatically reflected in AEM. Be careful about large changes such as switching Git branches. These can kill AEM Sync and potentially interfere with AEM itself if you happen to change a very large number of files while AEM Sync is running.

Comment: thanks, i installed intellivault and its a nice tool. I tried to pull a component from crx and after updates when i am trying to push to crx, its not updating crx. Any idea?

Comment: @Evan is it showing any errors when you try? If not, maybe the filters don't allow for this specific piece of content to be uploaded. Check your `filter.xml` files (more info [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/dev-tools/ht-vlttool.html) )

Comment: Its working, i added global-ignores = .vlt to my svn settings file & added [auto-props] as described @ https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/dev-tools/ht-vlttool.html. I am also ignoring .vlt & .svn in my filters.

Comment: I've added a gist to setup IntelliVault https://gist.github.com/newmizanur/0541cb29b6bc575e9eed4a9c3735fc21

Answer (score 0):

Aem sync works like a charm - https://github.com/gavoja/aemsync

Go to Terminal> CD to the directory where you have installed aemsync via npm > hit the command provided at the github page.